# Live feeds via Atom protocol

Tags: rss, apache-camel, atom-feed, atompub

I have to create a consumer that consumes feeds from an Atom service. The feeds should be consumed as and when anything is published on the atom server.

Currently I am using camel-atom protocol which polls the atom server every 60 seconds by default (this polling time can be reduced). Is any way (using any API) that I can just subscribe to the atom server and receive updates whenever they are posted?

Answer (score 1):

[Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29) servers are not pushing changes to subscribers. Published feeds (RSS and Atom) are a way to enable clients to automatically check for updates.

There is no option to configure [camel-atom](https://camel.apache.org/atom) other than `consumer.delay`, which sets the polling interval.

Answer (score 0):

As Cringe says, Atom itself is "just" a data format... not a protocol to distribute/consume data. There are several protocols which have been built around distrubuting and consuming Atom, starting with [Atompub](http://bitworking.org/projects/atom/rfc5023.html). However, the most popular these days is clearly [PubSubHubbub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSubHubbub) (supported by Wordpress, Blogger, Medium, Feedburner, Feedpress, Etsy... as well as many smaller/indie CMSes).

Check out [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com/subscriber) too (which I created!) which can help you turn any RSS/Atom feed into a stream to consume.